# Prove that at least one of those numbers is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Conjecture:

> Given a natural number $n>1$. Then there is a prime in the sequence
>   $$n+1,2n+1,\dots,(n-1)n+1$$

Tested for all $n<10,000,000$.

---

I found this: http://oeis.org/A034693

Comment: Just out of curiosity : how did you test it for $n$ up to $10^6$ ? What kind of tool did you use ? Or, did you code it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I use ANS Forth with my own tools from https://github.com/Lehs/ANS-Forth-libraries, using sets and prime tables. The test takes a few seconds.

Comment: I would be inclined to try proof by induction to start with

Comment: For $n=1$, the sequence is $2, 3, \ldots , 1$.

Comment: You might want to search up the Green-Tao theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem. Since for $n+1$, there is a sequence which has $n+1$ primes, you only have to shorten the conjecture to show that one of the primes is between $n+1$ and $(n-1)(n+1)$.

Comment: @Harry Take $n\geq2$ and think about starting problem. I think it's more better.

Comment: @Harry Surely, for $n=1$ the sequence would just be the number $2$? We are taking the value of $k$ from $k=1$ to $k=(n-1)$ and computing $kn+1$.

Comment: @Harry: Thanks!

Comment: @lioness99a If we were doing that, $k$ would go from $1$ to $0$. I think we can both agree though that the sequence is described by $\{ kn+1 \}_{k=1}^{n-1}$, so $n$ must necessarily be $2$ or greater.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80865/least-prime-in-a-arithmetic-progression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) 
states that, if $\gcd(a,n)=1$ then there exist infinitely many primes in
the arithmetic progression $a,a+n,a+2n,a+ 3n,\dots$

[Linnik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem)  proved that there are constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that the least prime $p(a,n)$ which is congruent to $a$ modulo $n$ satisfies $p(a,n)\leq c_1 n^{c_2}$.
Details about these constant $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80865/least-prime-in-a-arithmetic-progression

Your conjecture says that $p(1,n)\leq (n−1)n+1$ for any integer $n>1$.